# Object moved to here - Apache Jmeter

Tags: apache, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I got an error message `Object moved to here` when I try to run my url path("/Logon/UserLogon") on Apache Jmeter. Can anyone help me to solve this?

API url - `74.85.128.67/Logon/UserLogon`

**Passed Headers in browser**

[image]

**JMeter Running**

[image]

In the last image, you can see that it redirects to a home page(`74.85.128.67/Home`) initially and automatically redirects to log in (`74.85.128.67`) page. Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Although with so little information, it's hard to say anything for sure, but this error is returned by a server side. Ask developers of the application you are testing, or verify the difference between what browser is sending and your JMeter script (including headers, cookies).

Comment: @KirilS. I have updated the post. Can you check and help me?

Comment: @KirilS. Please find the following links of JMeter HTTP Request and Browser Cookies. http://screencast.com/t/bdtcd2r8zim and http://screencast.com/t/s3kJ189b2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably failed to pass the token _RequestVerificationToken that is returned as a header in a response you show.

You should use a Regex Extractor using Response Header content to extract this header to then inject it in subsequent queries.

Also, Ensure you add a CookieManager :

- https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-cookie-manager/

and if appliable that you handle the _ViewState, see:

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterTesting/ASPNETViewState

Answer (score 0):

From the responses in the Jmeter, I can see that this app is running on IIS. A quick search on the specific error you are seeing + IIS pointed me to msdn links which can explain why you are seeing this in the first place.

Here is the link to the page:

[MSDN Page on "Object Moved to Here Error"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/888418)